# Как "достать" элемент из регулярного выражения?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

У меня существует  переменная `version`, которая представлена, как регулярное выражение:

```
string verison= @"UPDATE  \s  SmartNotes  \s  for  \s  MSSQL  \s  v2.0  \s  (?'CreationDate'\d{4}  [-\.] \d{2}  [-\.]  \d{2})  .*  \.sql";
```

Как можно получить `CreationDate`? Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: что значит _получить "CreationDate"_?

Comment: @Duracell, стоит ознакомиться с [Когда стоит использовать внутристрочное выделение для кода?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Answer (score 2):

Существует ряд способов обращения к фрагменту текста, обработанного регулярным выражением:

- Именованные захватывающие группы (named capturing groups);
- Нумерованные захватывающие группы (numbered capturing groups);
- Вырезка фрагмента строки на основе найденного начала и конца совпадения.

Самое лучшее — используйте именованные группы (*Named Capturing Groups*):

```
foreach (Match m in mc){
    MessageBox.Show(m.Groups["creation_date"].Value);
}
```

Сама же именованная группа создаётся в регулярном выражении
таким образом:

```
(?<creation_date>.*?)
```

В вашем случае:

```
(?<creation_date>'CreationDate'\d{4}  [-\.] \d{2}  [-\.]  \d{2})
```

(то есть добавилось `<creation_date>` после `(?`).

В итоге та часть строки, которая будет соответствовать регулярном выражению
в скобках, окажется в `m.Groups["creation_date"].Value`.

Comment: спасибо за подробное объяснение!!

Comment: Множество это сколько? Есть ли варианты кроме: 1) захватывающие скобки 2) вырезка части строки по возвращенным началу и концу совпадения ?

Comment: @ReinRaus: Я знаю 3: (1) именованные или (2) неименованные захватывающие группы, (3) вырезка части строки. Может быть, можно придумать ещё, но по-моему широко распространённых методов больше нет

Comment: @ReinRaus: Обновил ответ, чтобы он лучше читался

Comment: Ок. Спасибо, теперь все хорошо.